# Ubuntu 17.04, Steam will not download content

Tags: steam, downloads, 17.04

After upgrading ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04, Steam will not download content but can login and browse the store fine.

I have already tried changing the download location multiple times and clearing the download cache.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Steam
2. sudo apt-get install libnss-resolve:i386
3. Open Steam

Works in Ubuntu 17.04 64bit.

More info: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4661